# Insertar varios datos separados por comas con php

Tags: php

un saludo.

Como puedo hacer para insertar varios datos separados por comas de acuerdo a una pregunta en especifica, por ejemplo:

Tengo dos preguntas en mi formulario y cada pregunta la estoy separando por el id_pregunta:

index.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_pregunta[]" value="1" readonly>                       
<input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" value="Cuales de los siguientes módulos te gustaría que tuviera" readonly>
    
<label>Cuáles de los siguientes módulos te gustaría que tuviera?</label>
    
<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[]" value="WhatsApp Business">WhatsApp Business

<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[]" value="Landing pages">Landing pages
              
<br><br>                    
                        
                        
<input type="hidden" name="id_pregunta[]" value="2" readonly>                       
<input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" value="Que tipos de mensajes envias" readonly>
                    
<label>Qué tipos de mensajes envías?</label>
                                    
<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[]" value="Promocionales">Promocionales

<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[]" value="Información general">Información general
```

Luego cuando presiono el botón de guardar pasa al archivo que procesa la información:

procesa.php

```
$id_pregunta= $_POST['id_pregunta'];
$pregunta= $_POST['pregunta'];
$respuno= $_POST['respuno'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($id_pregunta); $i++){          
       
       $id_pregunta[$i];
       $pregunta[$i];
       $respuno[$i];

            $sqltw="INSERT INTO des_resp(id_pregunta,pregunta,respuno) 
            VALUES ('".$id_pregunta[$i]."','".$pregunta[$i]."','".$respuno[$i]."')";
            $restw=mysqli_query($cn,$sqltw);
    
            
    }
```

Por medio del for el procesar es capaz de guardar una fila por cada pregunta y sus respectivas respuestas, solo que me permite guardar una pregunta por cada respuesta.

Y actualmente queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el gran detalle es que mis preguntas tienen más de una respuesta. Logre investigar bastante sobre eso de como poder separar las respuestas con comas en el caso de que se seleccionen varias respuestas por pregunta y ahora el código quedo de la siguiente forma:

procesa.php

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($id_pregunta); $i++){          
       
       $id_pregunta[$i];
       $pregunta[$i];
       $respuno[$i];
       
//este fue el código que agregue.

        $selectedos = '';
        $num_countriesdos = count($_POST['respuno']);
        $currentdos = 0;
        foreach ($_POST['respuno'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($currentdos != $num_countriesdos-1)
                $selectedos .= $value.', ';
            else
                $selectedos .= $value.'.';
            $currentdos++;
        }

            
            $sqltw="INSERT INTO des_resp(id_pregunta,pregunta,respuno) 
            VALUES ('".$id_pregunta[$i]."','".$pregunta[$i]."','".$selectedos."')";
            $restw=mysqli_query($cn,$sqltw);
    
            
    }
```

Agregando esas líneas de código ahora si quedan separadas las respuestas por comas y se guardan todas las respuestas que seleccione de cada pregunta.

El único problema es que esta guardando todas las respuestas en todas las preguntas de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No esta separando las respuestas por cada pregunta, esta insertando todas las respuestas en todas las preguntas y esta mal, la idea es que inserte cada respuesta en cada pregunta que corresponde.

No encuentro mi error, o de que forma podría mejorar el código.

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No logro entender muy bien, ¿Solo quieres almacenar todos los elementos de un `Array` (Las respuestas), en un `VARCHAR`, separados por **comas**?

Comment: Hola, así es. actualmente lo hace pero esta insertando todas las respuestas en todas las preguntas, no esta insertando cada respuesta que selecciono en la pregunta a la que corresponde.

Comment: ¿`$id_pregunta` es un `Array` verdad, que iteras con un `foreach`? creo que se cual es tu error, por favor comprueba que ese Array este llegando correctamente con un `var_dump()`

Comment: Si esta llegando bien.

Comment: Perfecto, ya agrego una respuesta a tu pregunta amigo

Comment: Por cierto, en tu código no queda claro de donde sale la variable `$_POST['pregunta']` ¿puedes agregar eso por favor?

Comment: Listo ya agregue el input que envía la pregunta oculta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que tus respuestas se inserten correctamente por pregunta, es mas conveniente que iteres en el **Array** `$id_pregunta` con el `foreach` y no las **respuestas**, ya que en cada valor de esta matriz esta el `id`; de la siguiente manera:

```php
$id_pregunta = $_POST['id_pregunta'];
$pregunta = $_POST['pregunta'];
$respuno = $_POST['respuno'];

foreach($id_pregunta as $key => $item){
  
  //Creamos un string a partir del Array, separado por comas
  $respuestas = implode(', ', $respuno[$key]);
  
  //Creamos la consulta y la ejecutamos
  $sqltw = "INSERT INTO des_resp(id_pregunta,pregunta,respuno) VALUES ('".$item."','".$pregunta[$key]."','".$respuestas."')";
  $restw = mysqli_query($cn,$sqltw);

}
```

Esto hace mas corto y legible el código gracias a la función [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode) de **PHP**, pero no soluciona tu problema. Tu problema reside en los `input` y lo puedes solucionar así:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="id_pregunta[]" value="1" readonly>                       
<input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" value="Cuales de los siguientes módulos te gustaría que tuviera" readonly>
    
<label>Cuáles de los siguientes módulos te gustaría que tuviera?</label>
    
<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[0][]" value="WhatsApp Business">WhatsApp Business

<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[0][]" value="Landing pages">Landing pages
              
<br><br>                    
                        
                        
<input type="hidden" name="id_pregunta[]" value="2" readonly>                       
<input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" value="Que tipos de mensajes envias" readonly>
                    
<label>Qué tipos de mensajes envías?</label>
                                    
<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[1][]" value="Promocionales">Promocionales

<input type="checkbox" name="respuno[1][]" value="Información general">Información general
```

Necesitas enviar un **Array multidimensional** para las respuestas, en el que estará metido un **Array** por cada pregunta, con sus respectivas respuestas. Puedes notar que lo identifico en **PHP** aquí `$respuno[$key]`

Esto debería funcionar para ti amigo ;)

Comment: Excelente, eso era lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Que gusto..!! por cierto, un pequeño dato, ten cuidado con las consultas a la base de datos dentro de un **bucle** (`for`, `foreach`, `while`), en este caso no hay problema porque solo serian **dos** iteraciones, pero en caso de ser **30**, **40**, **50** o muchas mas proprias presentar un problema. Saludos